# Why I have no warning when not all execution path in a function is returning the type hinted expression?

Tags: python, pycharm, type-hinting

I have the following function definition:

```
def my_func(value: int) -> int:
    if value > 10:
        return value + 1
    # return value (suppose, this is what I forgot here)
```

Many times I forgot the final return statement (in more complex cases) which causing the function accidentally return with None causing run-time error.

For this function definition PyCharm code inspection (all settings default) does not give any warnings. I would expect the inspection to discover, if there are execution paths which do not return with the type hinted function return type.

What am I missing?

Comment: I think that is what writing tests are for.

Comment: Use a different IDE, or find a plugin that does this? Vscode with the mypy linter can detect this exact case

Comment: linters can be added to PyCharm too, at that point the IDE/text editor is not what determines whether a case can be detected much, it just runs the linter

Comment: The simple reason I can think of is that Pycharm inspects ***existing*** code. You expect it to warn you about ***missing*** (non-existent) code. Anyway, I don't see what kind of answer you expect here. This could be [posted as an issue to Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/reporting-issues.html)

Comment: @James, your statement would be true for the majority of the warnings what linters do discover, so what is the difference?

Comment: this may be a case of needing strict-optional. Is there a setting for that in pycharm that needs turning on?

Comment: @Tomerikoo, thx this will be probably the answer, although smac89 wrote he got warning, so it is not a general rule for all linters. To answer your question, what kind of answer I expect(ed), I am beginner in Python, and also the ecosystem like its linters and IDEs, so I just wanted to know am I missing some trivial knowledge here or not. In C# compiler it is an error, so there is no theoretical limit to check only what is written and not detect what is missing.

Comment: Reading my comment again, it might have come off not nice. Sorry for that. Indeed there could be a setting missing which would be a valid answer. There is no such that I know of and indeed adding an explicit `return None` marks it with a warning of the wrong type. My suggestion still holds and you could totally open this as an issue for Pycharm. Worst case, they'll reject with the reason being it's possible already and let you know how